# Reopening closed Lion questions

Tags: discussion, lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should we do with closed questions about pre-release/beta software after the software has been released?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/580/what-should-we-do-with-closed-questions-about-pre-release-beta-software-after-the)

It looks like there are a bunch of Lion questions which were closed before Lion was officially shipping. Should we reopen these now?